# async/await functions not executing in the correct order

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await, twilio, sequelize.js

I have a sequence of async/await functions, but they seem to be executing in an order that suggests that execution is not being blocked by the `await` statements.  I'm using Twilio and Sequelize but I imagine the async problem can be diagnosed without knowledge of either of these two packages.  Sorry for posting so much code but I feel like I need to include all of it to explain the issue.

My main code is:

```
app.post('/sms',async function(req,res){
    try{
        worker=await worker.updateWorker('+18005559999',process.env.TWILIO_OFFLINE_SID);
        responseValue="/sms: worker "+worker.friendlyName+" updated to: "+worker.activityName;
        console.log(responseValue);
        res.status(200).send();

    }
    catch(err){
        console.log("/sms error: "+err);
    }
}
```

`worker.updateWorker()` is defined in an ES6 class as follows:

```
async updateWorker(contact_uri,activitySid){
        console.log("updateWorker: getting workerSid from database");
        workerSid=await database.getWorkerSid(contact_uri);
        console.log("updateWorker: workerSid is "+workerSid);
        worker=await this.updateWorkerFromSid(workerSid,activitySid);
        console.log("updateWorker: worker's friendlyName is "+worker.friendlyName);
        return worker;
    }
```

`database.getWorkerSid()` is:

```
getWorkerSid(contact_uri){
        return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
            sequelize.query("select * from worker where contact_uri='"+contact_uri+"'",
            { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT})
            .then(result=>{
                if(result.length==0){
                    resolve(null);
                }
                else{
                    resolve(result[0].sid);
                }
            })
            .catch(err=>reject(err));
        });
    }
```

`this.updateWorkerFromSid()` is:

```
async updateWorkerFromSid(workerSid,activitySid){
        var worker;
        try{
            worker=await this.workspace.workers(workerSid)
                        .update({
                            activitySid:activitySid
                        });
            console.log("updateWorkerFromSid: worker has been updated to activity: "+worker.activityName);
            return worker;
        }
        catch(err){
            console.log("updateWorkerFromSid error: "+err);
        }
        finally{
            return worker;
        }

    }
```

What I end up getting in the console is:

```
updateWorker: getting workerSid from database
Executing (default): select * from worker where contact_uri='+18005559999'
/sms error: ReferenceError: workerSid is not defined
```

So this makes me think that we get as far as the `sequelize.query()` call in `database.getWorkerSid()`, but then execution proceeds without waiting for the query promise to resolve, and on the line:

```
console.log("updateWorker: workerSid is "+workerSid);
```

the `workerSid` is undefined so there's a crash and the error propagates back up to the try/catch block in the main code.

Basically, what I'm trying to do is:

1. Get `workerSid` from database based on `contact_uri`
2. Use `workerSid` to update worker
3. Once update is complete, output information about the update to console

How should I have my async/await set up to ensure that the events happen in this order?

Comment: Did you not forget the `async` keyword in `getWorkerSid`? That's the only thing I can think of. Apart from that your code looks fine and you made sure to promisify everything that needs to be.

Comment: please console result from getWorkerSid function and update your question.

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Comment: You will want to use `let`/`const`/`var` to declare your variables as local!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I refactored `database.getWorkerSid()`, to get rid of the Promise constructor anti-pattern, as follows:

```
async getWorkerSid(contact_uri){
        var workerRow=await this.getRowFromWorkerTable(contact_uri);
        if (workerRow.length==0){
            return null;
        }
        else{
            return workerRow[0].sid;
        }
    }

getRowFromWorkerTable(contact_uri){
        return sequelize.query("select * from worker where contact_uri='"+contact_uri+"'",
        { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT});
    }
```

And I declared all my variables in class methods using `var`, e.g.

`var workerSid=await database.getWorkerSid(contact_uri);`

It works now.